# What actions you have taken after you hear about React Native Architecture Changing and Airbnb, Udacity abandon it?

Tags: react-native

This is not a technical question.
It just this is my first programming language which I am fluent and I don't want to abandon it. But I feel frustrated, I need to know about this framework, but should I learn something that will change in just a couple more weeks.

News:
https://adtmag.com/articles/2018/07/10/abandon-react-native.aspx
https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/07/26/node_native_developers/

Answer (score 2):

**Few things from my perspective:** Airbnb was supporting React Native since 2016, and recently they announced sunsetting React Native and reinvesting all of their efforts back into native because they weren’t able to achieve their specific goals. The reason why AirBnB is moving away from React Native **is very specific to Airbnb**. They already have a  huge number of IOS & Android Developers and feel their application needs are pretty unconventional. They end up developing for 3 platforms instead of 2. Which means their entire application is not in React Native, only a few features are in React Native. 
Read these articles: https://medium.com/braus-blog/airbnb-is-dropping-react-js-should-you-too-dcbff36def5c and Here goes what worked well and what didn’t : https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/react-native-at-airbnb-the-technology-dafd0b43838 . And one head's up from the RN team after the .56 version release is "

> We're working on a large-scale rearchitecture of React Native to make
>   the framework more flexible and integrate better with native
>   infrastructure in hybrid JavaScript/native apps. With this project,
>   we'll apply what we've learned over the last 5 years and incrementally
>   bring our architecture to a more modern one. We're rewriting many of
>   React Native's internals, but most of the changes are under the hood:
>   existing React Native apps will continue to work with few or no
>   changes."

Facebook has not stopped supporting React, and there are still a lot of contributors supporting and using React Native in the community.  Moving away from technology depends on what are the other alternatives you have.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. You bring me hope in this framework.

Comment: So Facebook will change React Native Architecture, so should I keep learning: react-native-payments, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-gifted-chat? or should I wait for completed changes?

Comment: @VũNguyễnDuyI guess you are using third-party libraries, which are developed and maintained by someone. if the someone will give 100% support and upgrade to his work, then you can go ahead a learn it. We will be able to find some plug-in or library for each functionality, but the library might end-up having compatibility issues and it might not behave like native one all the time.